# Why BigQuery produces an empty array when ARRAY_CONCAT is applied on a non empty array in conjunction with ARRAY_AGG?

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I encountered a very curious behavior in BigQuery.

The following query produces the unexpected result empty array `[]`, since I'm concatenating arrays I'm expecting an array with all the elements that I'm concatenating.

```
SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT(
    (
        SELECT ARRAY_AGG(col1) -- This is creating an empty array since condition is always false
        FROM ... 
        WHERE 1 = 2
    ),
    ['test']
)
```

While a very similar query produces the expected result `['test']`:

```
SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT(
    [],
    ['test']
)
```

And ARRAY_AGG() produces indeed an empty array `[]`:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(col1) -- This is creating an empty array since condition is always false
FROM ... 
WHERE 1 = 2
```

Why the first query produces an empty array while it is a combination of the second and third query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little tricky to explain.  Your first query does not produce an *empty array*.  It produce an array column whose value is `NULL`.  That is why the concat returns `NULL`.

As a general rule, almost aggregation function in a subquery with no rows returns `NULL`.  The only exception is `COUNT()` which returns `0`.

It is tempting to think that `NULL` and an empty array are the same thing.  They are not.